# How to use more params in $http.get and add them to url

Tags: angularjs

I follow an angular tutorial and because the link that I have to use in my service changed since the tutorial was made, I am confuse how to use the second param in params, which is the appid required now by the api.openweathermap.org.

```
function weatherFactory($http) {
    return {
        getWeather: function(city, country) {
            var query = city + ', ' + country;
            var key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            return $http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?', {
                params: {
                    q: query,
                    appid: key
                }
            }).then(function(response) {
                // //then() returns a promise which 
                // is resolved with return value of success callback
                return response.data.weather[0].description;
            });
        }
    };
}
```

The link should look like this:

```
http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1
```

So I put the key like the second params in get, but I don't know how to add this & in front of appid, to be like in the link example from them.
Can someone please tell me how to do it?

Comment: what your question exactly? , how to create the url?, how to add params?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like in this [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5668bugf/1/). The separator `&` is added automatically by AngularJS.

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?',
  params: {
    appid: 'b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1',
    q: 'London,uk'
  }
}).then(function(response) {
   return response.data.weather[0].description;
});
```

Result:

> http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1&q=London,uk

Answer (score 1):

> but I don't know how to add this `&` in front of appid, to be like in the link example from them

`&` is the separator character for query strings. It should be added when converting the object you pass to `params` to a query string.

You aren't converting the object to a query string. Angular is.  So **do nothing**. Angular will do that for you.

---

If you were converting it manually, you would do something like:

```
var pairs = [];
Object.keys(obj.params).forEach(function (key) {
    pairs.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(params[key]));
});
var query_string = pairs.join("&");
```

… but as mentioned above. That's done for you by the library.